# how can I know how many rows will update sql affected before I execute it

Tags: php, mysql

whe can see how many record will be selected in this sql bellow using explain:

```
explain select * from products
```

[image]
but expain is not for update and delete command.
In php, I want to update an table using a sql , I want to check weather this sql will update only row or many rows , if many rows affected , this sql is not allow to run for  preventing the table misoperation.
so how can I know how many rows will this update sql affected before I execute it?

```
update products set products_model = 'hello' where products_id = '1'
```

Comment: You can do this, but it's not totally safe. What if someone adds another matching row after you do the check? Why isn't `products_id` a unique key? Then there can't be more than one row that will be updated.

Comment: If your goal is to make sure no more than one row gets updated, you can do `UPDATE . . . WHERE . . .  LIMIT 1`.  No matter how many rows match the WHERE clause, only one will be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the query with

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS will_affect_rows_count FROM products WHERE products_id = '1'
```

This will give you the count of the rows that will be affected by your UPDATE query.

Might I ask why you can have products in this table with duplicated products_id's?

Comment: only for example , no strict.

Comment: Ok. Otherwise if you are going to have duplicated ids, running the `select` & `update` queries in a transaction or doing `select for update` is something you might consider doing.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got a unique row index 'id' you could do

```
SELECT id FROM yourtable WHERE updateCondition;
```

And then do your update with

```
UPDATE yourtable SET foo=bar WHERE updateCondition AND id in (<ids returned by first query here>);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `select` before hand:

```
select count(*)
from products 
where products_id = '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you should execute `SELECT COUNT(*) from products WHERE products_id = '1'` before and watch the count

if it is == 1 then update