# Take the MYSQL affected rows return from update statement to solve the synchronization problem

Tags: mysql

for example, a field name status can only set to 0 once. To prevent the synchronization problem, can I take affected rows to judge whether the operation is allowed?

- If affected rows return 1 means ok ,
- If affected rows return 0 means the status has been set.

any help is appreciated

Comment: So what you mean to say is, in any case your query will be run, and you would like to count the number of rows affected to determine whether the state has already been set?

Comment: If you want to check how many rows are affected (or which rows are affected) before executing update you can re-use the solution here according to your requirements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645672/how-can-i-know-how-many-rows-will-update-sql-affected-before-i-execute-it

Comment: @Meh yes, you got what i mean .

Comment: Check the solution I've given in the second comment, I feel it is a more efficient way to do this instead of running update and then checking the affected rows.

Comment: but execute a select statement before update may cause synchronization issue.@Meh